# Importing arrow positions and directions from a text file

Tags: python, scripting, import

How can I import position and direction data into blender and place 3D arrows on those points?
I have made a custom 3D arrow in blender that I want to be duplicated and re-positioned.

For example, data for 2 arrows might be

`{{0,0,1},{1,1,0}}`

`{{0,0,-1},{0,2,0}}`

Where the first three elements are the `x,y,z` positions and the next three are the lengths along those directions.

I have not used Blender with a Python script before.

Comment: does it have to be python? it should be pretty easy with e.g. the free add-on animation nodes.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I have lists of more than 20 arrows, so I would like to be able to paste the arrow data in somehow. Is that possible with animation nodes?

Comment: of course. Either you can have the data in a txt file (or csv) or whatever and animation nodes just reads it ...or you paste e.g. your data in the text editor of blender and animation nodes will read the data from there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```py
import bpy
from bpy import context as C, data as D
from mathutils import Vector

arrow = D.objects['arrow']

with open("E:/arrows.txt") as f:
    lines = f.read().strip().splitlines()

eval_vector = lambda s: Vector(map(float, s.split(',')))
    
for line in lines:
    start, vector = map(eval_vector, line[2:-2].split('},{'))
    new_arrow = arrow.copy()
    new_arrow.location = start
    new_arrow.rotation_euler = vector.to_track_quat('Z', 'Y').to_euler()
    C.collection.objects.link(new_arrow)
```

For your input gives:

[image]

The arrow with yellow outline (active object) is the starting arrow used for duplication. You can add `new_arrow.scale *= vector.length` to control the length of the arrows:

[image]

And if you change your input to use JSON, the code can become simpler:

```
[[[0,0,1],[1,1,0]],
[[0,0,-1],[0,2,0]]]
```

```py
import bpy, json
from bpy import context as C, data as D
from mathutils import Vector

arrow = D.objects['arrow']

with open("E:/arrows.txt") as f:
    data = json.load(f)
    
for start, lengths in data:
    new_arrow = arrow.copy()
    new_arrow.location = start
    v = Vector(lengths)
    new_arrow.rotation_euler = v.to_track_quat('Z', 'Y').to_euler()
    new_arrow.scale *= v.length
    C.collection.objects.link(new_arrow)
```

Comment: Thanks very much - is there a way I could just paste the arrow data into the script?

Comment: very nice solution! Learnt some new bpy/vector funcs i didn't know +10 (unfortunately i could only give 1)

Comment: @MattMajic [multiline string](https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_multi_line_strings.asp) + use `json.loads` instead.